# How to map from external system deserialized pojo?

Tags: java, jackson, modelmapper

I have a response I receive like this:

```
    {
     
      "contactPersons": [
        {
          "contactCrmId":"1232445", 
          "contactUserType": {
            "code": "NORMAL"
          },
          "contactName": "",
          "contacts": [
            {
              "contactType": {
                "code": "E-Mail"
              },
              "contactValue": "test@test.com"
            },
            {
              "contactType": {
                "code": "Mobile"
              },
              "contactValue": "0505566777"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

The POJO I made for this is:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "contactType",
    "contactValue"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Contact {

    @JsonProperty("contactType")
    private ContactType contactType;
    @JsonProperty("contactValue")
    private String contactValue;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("contactType")
    public ContactType getContactType() {
        return contactType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactType")
    public void setContactType(ContactType contactType) {
        this.contactType = contactType;
    }

    public Contact withContactType(ContactType contactType) {
        this.contactType = contactType;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactValue")
    public String getContactValue() {
        return contactValue;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactValue")
    public void setContactValue(String contactValue) {
        this.contactValue = contactValue;
    }

    public Contact withContactValue(String contactValue) {
        this.contactValue = contactValue;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public Contact withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(Contact.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
        sb.append("contactType");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contactType == null)?"<null>":this.contactType));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("contactValue");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contactValue == null)?"<null>":this.contactValue));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("additionalProperties");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
        sb.append(',');
        if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
            sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contactType == null)? 0 :this.contactType.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contactValue == null)? 0 :this.contactValue.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof Contact) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        Contact rhs = ((Contact) other);
        return ((((this.contactType == rhs.contactType)||((this.contactType!= null)&&this.contactType.equals(rhs.contactType)))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))))&&((this.contactValue == rhs.contactValue)||((this.contactValue!= null)&&this.contactValue.equals(rhs.contactValue))));
    }

}
```

```
JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "contactCrmId",
    "contactUserType",
    "contactName",
    "contacts"
})
@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class ContactPerson {

    @JsonProperty("contactCrmId")
    private String contactCrmId;
    @JsonProperty("contactUserType")
    private ContactUserType contactUserType;
    @JsonProperty("contactName")
    private String contactName;
    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("contactCrmId")
    public String getContactCrmId() {
        return contactCrmId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactCrmId")
    public void setContactCrmId(String contactCrmId) {
        this.contactCrmId = contactCrmId;
    }

    public ContactPerson withContactCrmId(String contactCrmId) {
        this.contactCrmId = contactCrmId;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactUserType")
    public ContactUserType getContactUserType() {
        return contactUserType;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactUserType")
    public void setContactUserType(ContactUserType contactUserType) {
        this.contactUserType = contactUserType;
    }

    public ContactPerson withContactUserType(ContactUserType contactUserType) {
        this.contactUserType = contactUserType;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactName")
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contactName")
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public ContactPerson withContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    @JsonProperty("contacts")
    public void setContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public ContactPerson withContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        return this;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    public ContactPerson withAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(ContactPerson.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
        sb.append("contactCrmId");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contactCrmId == null)?"<null>":this.contactCrmId));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("contactUserType");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contactUserType == null)?"<null>":this.contactUserType));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("contactName");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contactName == null)?"<null>":this.contactName));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("contacts");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.contacts == null)?"<null>":this.contacts));
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append("additionalProperties");
        sb.append('=');
        sb.append(((this.additionalProperties == null)?"<null>":this.additionalProperties));
        sb.append(',');
        if (sb.charAt((sb.length()- 1)) == ',') {
            sb.setCharAt((sb.length()- 1), ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contactCrmId == null)? 0 :this.contactCrmId.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.additionalProperties == null)? 0 :this.additionalProperties.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contactUserType == null)? 0 :this.contactUserType.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contactName == null)? 0 :this.contactName.hashCode()));
        result = ((result* 31)+((this.contacts == null)? 0 :this.contacts.hashCode()));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((other instanceof ContactPerson) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        ContactPerson rhs = ((ContactPerson) other);
        return ((((((this.contactCrmId == rhs.contactCrmId)||((this.contactCrmId!= null)&&this.contactCrmId.equals(rhs.contactCrmId)))&&((this.additionalProperties == rhs.additionalProperties)||((this.additionalProperties!= null)&&this.additionalProperties.equals(rhs.additionalProperties))))&&((this.contactUserType == rhs.contactUserType)||((this.contactUserType!= null)&&this.contactUserType.equals(rhs.contactUserType))))&&((this.contactName == rhs.contactName)||((this.contactName!= null)&&this.contactName.equals(rhs.contactName))))&&((this.contacts == rhs.contacts)||((this.contacts!= null)&&this.contacts.equals(rhs.contacts))));
    }

}
```

And I want to map into my contact object like this that is swagger generated:

```
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-07-18T19:30:20.680014600+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]")
public class Contact implements Payload {

  private String name;

  private String mobileNumber;

  private String emailId;

  public Contact name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get name
   * @return name
  */
  
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Contact mobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get mobileNumber
   * @return mobileNumber
  */
  
  @JsonProperty("mobileNumber")
  public String getMobileNumber() {
    return mobileNumber;
  }

  public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
  }

  public Contact emailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get emailId
   * @return emailId
  */
  
  @JsonProperty("emailId")
  public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
  }

  public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Contact contact = (Contact) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.name, contact.name) &&
        Objects.equals(this.mobileNumber, contact.mobileNumber) &&
        Objects.equals(this.emailId, contact.emailId);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, mobileNumber, emailId);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Contact {\n");
    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    mobileNumber: ").append(toIndentedString(mobileNumber)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    emailId: ").append(toIndentedString(emailId)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

The pojos were generated using a library. Is there any way this can be done using modelmapper? I would like to have ContactPerson map to generated Contact. Or do I do this without any mapper library?